# Is there any case that a method should not be the prototype method?

Tags: javascript

Just thinking of in Javascript, normally we put method inside prototype which can avoid code duplication.

I am wondering if there is real cases that we need to put method as non-prototype method? If yes, could you provide some examples.

Comment: Do you mean the difference between `obj.property` and `obj.prototype.property` ?

Comment: Prototypes are a memory conservation technique. You can avoid duplicate code without using prototypes.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine an object which represents animals. All animals can walk, so let's add a `walk()` function as prototype.

```
function Animal(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype.walk = function () {

    console.log(this.name + ' is walking');
};
```

You can now create an instance:

```
var cat = new Animal('Cat');
cat.walk();
```

However some animals are different from others. For example a cat can't bark, but a dog can. So the `bark()` function can't be part of the prototype. You need to add it to the instance.

```
var dog = new Animal('Dog');
dog.bark = function () {

    console.log(this.name + ' is barking');
};

dog.walk();
dog.bark();
```

Comment: This is true if there is only one dog in the world, but Dog could be a type that extends the Animal prototype, in which case it too would have a prototype.

Comment: If the application needs to represent only the types of animals, then there is no need to create multiple instances of a dog. Anyway, this is just an example.